# Selecting ALL rows which has a max value in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, select

table for visualization

```
item     title    numTimesPurchased
1        Beer     30
2        Chips    13
3        Smokes   30
4        Gum      3
```

Code I've written so far

```
SELECT Purchase.item, Item.title, SUM(quantity) AS numTimesPurchased 
FROM Item 
INNER JOIN Purchase ON Item.id = Purchase.item 
GROUP BY item, title;
```

I need to select all columns in the row/ multiple rows where which has a MAX value in numTimePurchased. So in this table, both item 1 and 3 should be selected.

I've tried sorting the data using ORDER BY and LIMIT but it will not work with data sets where there are more than one row with a max value, is there another way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 2):

One nice way to handle this on MySQL 8+ uses the `RANK` analytic function:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT p.item, i.title, SUM(quantity) AS numTimesPurchased,
           RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(quantity) DESC) rnk
    FROM Item i
    INNER JOIN Purchase p ON i.id = p.item
    GROUP BY p.item, i.title
)

SELECT item, title, numTimesPurchased
FROM cte
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

A way to handle this on earlier versions of MySQL uses a non correlated subquery in the `HAVING` clause to check the number of times purchased:

```sql
SELECT p.item, i.title, SUM(quantity) AS numTimesPurchased
FROM Item i
INNER JOIN Purchase p ON i.id = p.item
GROUP BY p.item, i.title
HAVING SUM(quantity) = (SELECT SUM(quantity)
                        FROM Item i
                        INNER JOIN Purchase p ON i.id = p.item
                        GROUP BY p.item, i.title
                        ORDER BY SUM(quantity) DESC
                        LIMIT 1);
```

Comment: `Item` usage in the subquery (code for 5.x version) is obviously excess.

Comment: thank you! the second solution was the most understandable for a mysql beginner

Comment: @Akina No, not all, because the inner join might be discarding certain quantity values for non matches.  We want to ensure that we take the max quantity only from a set of values which the actual outer query would be considering.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen True, the purchase of non-existent item is possible - in theory.

Comment: Why use a cte instead of a subquery?

Comment: @ysth This affects on neither plan nor execution time (I have never seen the difference in practice at least). Subquery usage may make sense in old PostgreSQL which matherializes CTEs unconditionally, but OP uses MySQL.

Comment: @ysth I wasn't going to answer your comment, but since Akina largely did, I will add that for the purposes of giving a readable answer, I find it tidier to have a CTE which introduces the analytic function separate from the query.  As I have written above, the outer query makes it very clear that we just want rank = 1 records in the result set.

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH cte AS ( SELECT Purchase.item, Item.title, SUM(quantity) AS numTimesPurchased 
                   , MAX(SUM(quantity)) OVER () maxsum
              FROM Item 
              INNER JOIN Purchase ON Item.id = Purchase.item 
              GROUP BY item, title )
SELECT * FROM cte WHERE numTimesPurchased = maxsum
```

`MAX(SUM(quantity)) OVER ()` in CTE calculates maximal value (of `SUM(quantity) = numTimesPurchased`) within all rows. Outer query hence filters the rows where `numTimesPurchased` is not equal to this maximal value (formally not less needed, but the value above maximal value cannot exist).

PS. I hope that `quantity` is **not** of float or double datatype. But if it is then `SUM(quantity)` (both expressions in CTE) must be rounded to reasonable accuracy.

Comment: This answer would benefit from some surrounding words of explanation. SO hope to encourage people to come to SO to *learn* rather than just get someone else to do their work for them

Comment: @pp182 Simply replace an asterisk in `SELECT *` with definite columns list.